# Why Google Chrome behaves strangely compared to other browsers in viewing this page?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple HTML with a simple CSS which should display a 3x3 images grid.

```css
img {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
}

p {
 font-family: Raleway;
 margin-left: 1.66%;
 font-size: 23px;
 font-weight: 800;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
 width: 30%;
 padding-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Abu/Muhammad</p>
    <!-- Massimo Margagnoni -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8450/8026519634_f33f3724ea_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7218/7209301894_c99d3a33c2_h.jpg">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7231/6947093326_df216540ff_b.jpg">

    <!-- Giuseppe Milo -->
    <img src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8788/17367410309_78abb9e5b6_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5814/20700286354_762c19bd3b_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5647/21137202535_404bf25729_b.jpg">

    <!-- GörlitzPhotography -->
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5588/14991687545_5c8e1a2e86_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3888/14878097108_5997041006_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7579/15482110477_0b0e9e5421_b.jpg">

    <!-- All Photos Licensed Under Creative Commons 2.0 -->
    <!-- https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/legalcode  --> 
  </body>
</html>
```

When viewing the page in firefox, Edge and even IE 11, it works as expected.
But, when viewing the page in Chrome it shows the following:

[image: Chrome wrong display image]

I tried disabling all extension, resetting and even reinstalling chrome with no success.

What works for me is including Normalize.css.
Also and alternatively, changing the default body margin to be less than the default value: 8px.

I have a windows 10 pro with the setting of the size of texts, apps and other items set to 175%.

Is it possible to have Chrome behave like other browsers without including external css and changing the default css values?

Comment: It is not about the Chrome indeed, but with your images: the second one has other aspect ratio then all the others... cheers

Comment: Why Chrome on other machines does not have this issue?

Comment: I am not a browser developer and cannot answer it, but as a front-end developer I can tell you that you can prevent this browser issues using correct CSS, or at the end by using server side scripts or javascript.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome v74